# tracking list to tack if users are using an app

Tags: sharepoint-online

Good day

I am new to power platorm.
I have a tasks where i need to track if users are using an app, i need to track it with the sharepoint list. I need to create a new sharepoint list where i can populate the info into the new list and mabe using the create colum and one other colums to see if any iteams were credtaed for the day, if no items were created, then send an email at the end of the day to the owner. I should use a scheduled flow.

Thanks